Pick the latest file based on datestamp provided in the filename
I have to pick the latest files and copy it to the target folder. For example below are my files in C:\Users\ and the date stamp is after the third underscore i.e. 20240210 in the first file below. so out of 4 files below, AAA_PPP_51_20240302 is the first file. How do I do this in Informatica PowerCenter?
1.AAA_PPP_51_20240210
2.AAA_PPP_51_20240217
3.AAA_PPP_51_20240224
4.AAA_PPP_51_20240302


use a command task or pre-session command task to create a list file with latest file. Then load only that file.

use command ls -Art | tail -n 1 > file_list.txt
use file_list.txt in session as a file input. And use indirect file read in session.

If you are using Windows, then you have to create a bat file and call it in command task in Infa. You can use below script and save it as my_command.bat
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set LAST=%%i
echo  %LAST% >file_list.txt


Or even omit the file list by doing a copy of latest file to AAA_PPP_load.temp for example and reading just this single file in your mapping. If you always need to load only one file.

can it be done using java code in a mapping?

of course, you can do using java. You have to create script + call using informatica or some scheduler
